# How snakemake handles file/directories updates?

Tags: workflow, snakemake

I'm a bit confused about how snakemake (7.22.0) handles cache and file/directories updates.

I have the following simple demo workflow.(see description below).

I have a data directory with input.txt inside.

When I run the workflow for the first time, everything is fine.

```
snakemake -c1 report.html
```

If I do it again, nothing is done, as all is already done. Ok.

Then, I want to modify one of my output directories to see how snakemake handles the change. I expect it to replay the rules affected by this change.

I tried `touch data/dir1`

But when I run the command again,

```
snakemake -c1 report.html
```

Nothing happens. I was expecting execution of at leat augmentation1 and report rules.
I also tried using --touch command line option with no success.

Is it the way it is supposed to work ?

I was expecting that a change in output directory would trigger rules again.
I also tested with `--rerun-trigger mtime`option.

[image: Simple Workflow]

```
rule all:
    input:
        "report.html"

rule load:
    input:
        "data/input.txt"
    output:
        directory("data/dir1/"),
        directory("data/dir2/")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output[0]}
        mkdir -p {output[1]}
        """

rule augmentation1:
    input:
        "data/dir1/"
    output:
        directory("data/dir_aug1")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output}
        """

rule augmentation2:
    input:
        "data/dir2/"
    output:
        directory("data/dir_aug2")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output}
        """

rule report:
    input:
        "data/dir_aug1",
        "data/dir_aug2"
    output:
        "report.html"
    shell:
        "touch report.html"
```

Comment: I haven't carefully followed your question, but I wonder if you are hitting this bug https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2011.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I read the code, and I'm unsure I'm facing this bug.
When deleting a directory, I can see it missing in summary using (--summary) but no action is taken by snakemake on next workflow run as plan is set to "no update".